# Stub private controller methods in Rails / RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

Having trouble with this simple test:

#### book_spec.rb

```
let(:books_controller) { BooksController.new }

context "GET #index" do
  it "calls Book.all" do
    Book.should_receive(:all)
    book_controller.index
  end
end
```

#### books_controller.rb

```
def index
  respond_with books
end

private

def books
  @books ||= Book.all
end
```

I want to stub out calls to ActiveRecord so that it doesn't need to interact with the DB and speeds up the tests. However I just can't seem to get this right.

### Edit:

Sorry forgot the most important bit!

```
 Failure/Error: book_controller.index
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `variant' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: What is the problem? You get an error, failed tests or test triggers request to DB?

Comment: @gotva Sorry, included the error message.

Comment: hmmm... Google returns a lot of suggestions. I think [this one](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1097) is very similar to yours problem and the main idea is `You can't test controllers like this due to how the Rails application life cycle works.`. What about to write "classic" controller spec and stub `Book.all` there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing controllers in Rails by instantiating the controller is going to be difficult. Most controller tests invoke the controller action using Rspec's `get` method. Try something like:

```
context "GET #index" do
  it "calls Book.all" do
    expect(Book).to receive(:all)
    get :index
  end
end
```

If you really don't want to touch ActiveRecord then you can stub `Book` by changing the test to something like:

```
let(:book) { double(:book, all: true) }

context "GET #index" do
  it "calls Book.all" do
    stub_const("Book", book) 
    expect(Book).to receive(:all)
    get :index
  end
end
```

However, I don't think that you are going to get much speed improvements trying to stub active record here. Loading the Rails environment, when you run your tests, is the biggest time overhead - especially for a small test suite.

Comment: Great thanks the first solution works, haven't tried the second. I'll have to discuss stubbing out AR with the team.

Comment: What about the #find method. I just tried to write a test and used the request `get :show` which doesn't work. However `get :show, :id => 1` works. The 1 obviously being hardcoded. Normally I'd do `id => @book.id` however there's no `@book` here. Any ideas?

Comment: You can create a new instance of Book and assign it to `@book` (perhaps using FactoryGirl) and then call `get :show, id: @book.id`. Alternately you can just use a double with an arbitrary Id.